# What is the speed of light in geometrical optics?

Tags: speed-of-light, hamiltonian-formalism, geometric-optics

Geometrical optics or [Hamiltonian optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_optics) is the short wave length limit of Maxwells equations of light. In Hamiltonian form it is equivalent to the Hamiltonian description of a single, classical, non-relativistic particle with mass $m$.

However in non-relativistic, classical mechanics it is sometimes said, that the speed of light is assumed to be infinite. But I believe it must be assumed, that the speed of light is at least finite (but probably not invariant for inertial observers?) for the theory to make sense. But I'm not sure. What is the assumed speed of light within the framework of this theory?

Comment: The speed of light is *not* infinite in non-relativistic classical mechanics, nor in classical electromagnetism. Actually, the relation $c = {\mu_0 \epsilon_0}^{-1/2}$ was used in the 1800s to measure the speed of light, and Maxwell himself realized that light and magnetism were connected by noticing that the speed of propagation of a magnetic field is the same as the speed of light.

Comment: There is no need to assume a speed of light. The value has been known since long before Special Relativity was invented.

Comment: Can you point me to a source where Hamiltonian optics involves any notion of time?

Comment: @Sanya What about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle , the principle that the path taken between two points by a ray of light is the path that can be traversed in the least time? "Fermat's principle has the same form as Hamilton's principle and it is the basis of Hamiltonian optics."

Comment: @asmaier I see that physically, Fermat's principle and Hamiltonian optics have the same meaning. Mathematically, the equations of Hamiltonian optics do not have time as a variable, so I still cannot see how dynamical processes are meaningful within this framework. Maybe that's just me ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the construction of geometrical optics, no assumption is made on the speed of light. One can construct the Fermat principle and associated approximations even in fully relativistic formalism. (An example can be found in the book Gravitation by Misner, Thorne and Wheeler.)

On the other hand, if deriving non-relativistic mechanics from relativity, we *do* assume that the constituents of the mechanical system move at speeds $v$ much smaller than the speed of light $c$ in our lab frame. I.e. $v/c \approx 0$ *and our lab frame plays a privileged role*.

The fact that both classical mechanics and ray optics both have a Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formulation does not mean they are both ``nonrelativistic" in some sense or that they can be derived using some unified limit - they are not. In fact, even fully relativistic particle mechanics have a [Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Lagrangian_mechanics). This is because the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian formalism is more of a mathematical method how to describe dynamics of a broad class of systems.

But! Your are correct that using Hamiltonian optics and generally any light dynamics along with non-relativistic mechanics *leads to a weird inelegant system*. Namely, weird extra terms pop up e.g. in [dispersion relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation) of light when transforming between reference frames using [Galilean transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_invariance).

This was often historically hand-waived away by saying that the "nice" equations for the propagation of light are defined with respect to the reference frame of the medium and this also lead to the [postulation of aether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_special_relativity#Aether_and_electrodynamics_of_moving_bodies), the ``vacuum medium". Ultimately, this weird aether business and the [Michelson-Morley experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment) lead Einstein to his special relativity.

So the "classical" or "non-relativistic" sets of theories for light and massive particles are not quite consistent and one cannot really expect them to be. (They are quite useful nonetheless...)

Comment: So are you saying Hamiltonian optics is not Lorentz invariant? This is interesting, because one derives Hamiltonian optics as the short wave-length limit to Maxwells equations, which are Lorentz invariant. Why do we "loose" Lorentz invariance when doing the short wave-length limit?

Comment: @asmaier Hamiltonian optics is Lorenz invariant (if you treat media correctly), but historically people used Hamiltonian optics *and* assumed that the fundamental symmetry of all physics is Galilean relativity which lead to the conflicts described above.

Answer (score -5):

Similar to what Sammy Gerbil said, the speed of light doesn't have to be assumed, because the value of speed is c=3.00*10^8 m/s. However, it is disputed that different kinds of mechanics can cause different speeds of light. Like the chart below:
[image: a table of the change in the speed of light for classical mechanics]

And similar to valerio92, Maxwell did realize that light and magnetism were connect together.  The speed of propagation in a magnetic field is the same as the speed of light.
hope this helps :)

Comment: "It is disputed that different kind of mechanics can cause different speeds of light". Where did you get that from? Sounds like nonsense to me. Also, this image is supposed to illustrate the fact that you should use relativistic mechanics when the relative speeds between particles are comparable to the speed of light.